# @media screen and (min-width:1026px) not working on specific page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries

The pagetitle "Kasse" doesnt indent to the max-with of 1140px at desktop version. Here is the page where it doesn't work: https://www.paastoa.com/kasse/ (You have to put one item to the cart, to see the page, so open this link first: https://www.paastoa.com/?add-to-cart=2651 and then press the button "Weiter zur Kasse")

Here an example, of a page where it worked (with the same CSS): https://www.paastoa.com/forum/intervallfasten/

And this is the code for the ".site-main"-class, which is the parent class of ".header" (in thich the page-title is):

```
@media screen and (max-width:1025px) {
    .site-main {
        max-width: 1140px!important;
        padding: 10px 30px 50px 30px!important
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1026px) {
    .site-main {
        max-width: 1140px!important;
        padding: 50px 0 50px 0!important
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help and if you need more details, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this element with inline style, you should remove the style from the element.

```
<section class="elementor-element elementor-element-4db61fc1 elementor-section-stretched elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-id="4db61fc1" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;stretch_section&quot;:&quot;section-stretched&quot;}" style="width: 1583px; left: 0px;">
```

And here's the fix for your CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1026px) {
    .site-main {
        max-width: 1140px!important;
        padding: 50px 0 50px 0!important;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

.elementor-1137 .elementor-element.elementor-element-4db61fc1 {
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 1026px) {
    .site-main {
        max-width: 1140px!important;
        padding: 50px 0 50px 0!important;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

Was enough to fix it, thank you very much.